# How to do simple YAML parsing with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, jackson-databind

I have been seeking to use Jackson to parse YAML files so that I can process the information in them. I have done several searches, on the Jackson pages and on the Internet, and I am finding very good information about:

1. Reading YAML information and placing data into a Java POJO
2. Converting a java POJO into a YAML file
3. Converting YAML file contents into JSON (very useful for certain web applications!)

What I would like to do, however, is to use Jackson to read and parse an arbitrary YAML file, and return an object that represents the information in that file. Jackson has that capability with JSON files (though its ObjectMapper also provides conversions from and to POJOs). Can Jackson be used in a similar manner with YAML files? If so, how would one go about doing so?

Comment: Jackson is a JSON parser; **not** a YAML parser. Try [snakeyaml](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src).

Comment: Actually: According to the Jackson site and several other Internet sources, Jackson parses YAML as well as JSON. In fact, there are plenty of code examples showing its use to perform the 3 activities I mentioned in my post. And for varipus reasons (related to my boss' orders) I cannot use SnakeYAML. Otherwise, my problem would have been solved days ago.

Comment: Do you have [jackson-dataformats-text](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text)? Post your pom and enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: SnakeYAML is exactly the component of Jackson that does what you want. While SnakeYAML is an own project, Jackson uses it for YAML parsing, so if you depend on Jackson you also depend on SnakeYAML. It does not make sense to say you cannot use SnakeYAML when you use Jackson.